# How to add allow response header to all django views?

Tags: django, django-views, http-headers

How can I add the "Allow" header that specifies the allowed HTTP methods to the response headers of all Django views?
To be more clear, here is an example:

Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS

Comment: Function-based views can not specify what headers are allowed, since it is just a function.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for your response. I literally mean the 'allow' header, not specifying some headers that are allowed. Please see my edited question.

Comment: yes I understood that, but for a fbv, you can not derive what HTTP methods are allowed: that is procedural code, and as a consequence of Rice's theorem, we thus can not determine that in general.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your comment. Now it's more clear, thanks. By the way, Is it possible to do that for class-based views? Similar to what DRF is doing for its API routes.

Comment: yes, since these are specified in the view. There is even a method for these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For class-based views, you can add a mixin that will determine this. Indeed:

```
class AllowViewMixin:
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
        response.headers['Allow'] = ', '.join(self._allowed_methods())
        return response
```

then you can mix this in the class-based views, for example a `ListView`:

```
class MyListView(AllowViewMixin, ListView):
    # …
```